# I am seeing an error relating to this -'var argv = process.argv.slice (2)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I apologize before hand if this question is remedial but I am have a project stopping error.

The two errors are as follows:-

> ./../.sharedlibrary/nodejs/Excite.js: line 2: syntax error near
>   unexpected token
>
> ./../.sharedlibrary/nodejs/Excite.js: line 2:'var argv =
>   process.argv.slice(2) ;

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/local/src/node-v0.10.15-linux-x64/bin/node
var argv = process.argv.slice(2);
var snonce = argv[0];
var password = argv[1];
var skew = argv[2];
var JauthStarted = 0;
function ResetJauth()
{
    JauthStarted =0;
}
function reportError(msg,url,line) {
    var str = "" + " Jscript err: " + msg + " on line: "
            + line + " URL: " + url + " Browser: "
            + navigator.appName + " " + navigator.appVersion;
    document.loginbox.jerror.value = str;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Without your actual code, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: I'm confident it doesn't say "tocken"

Comment: What's in `process.argv`? Does it actually have enough elements to slice?